# How to add extra status in a kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application running in a kubernetes pod. User has options to enabled/disabled plugin for this application thru a set of REST API. One of the requirement is that user can use API to check what plugin is enabled/disabled.

Is there a way for me to report extra status in the pod status so that I can run a script in my pod to show what is enabled or not? Then the API can just directly retrieve the Pod object and display a list of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) and/or [annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/):

> You can use either labels or annotations to attach metadata to
> Kubernetes objects. Labels can be used to select objects and to find
> collections of objects that satisfy certain conditions. In contrast,
> annotations are not used to identify and select objects. The metadata
> in an annotation can be small or large, structured or unstructured,
> and can include characters not permitted by labels.

Kubernetes `labels` and `annotations` are both ways of adding metadata to Kubernetes objects. Kubernetes labels allow you to identify, select and operate on Kubernetes objects. Annotations however are non-identifying metadata. Therefore I believe that on your use case `labels` would fit better.